# Unallocated Space showing up as sublist in GParted while Extending Root Partition(Screenshots attached)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, root, boot-partition

Hi i am using dual boot(Windows 8.1) and Ubuntu 18.04.4 and trying to extend my root partition of ubuntu.I had three partitions for ubuntu (root which is about 20GB,home which is about 75GB,swap which is about 4 GB). Now my root partition was filled up so i decided to extend my root partition.For this i followed the following steps:

1. I logged in to Windows 8.1 and then created an unallocated space of around 25GB which is just next(left) to my root partition.
2. Next i used a live usb(which has ubuntu 18.04.4 in it) to boot up the machine.
3. Then i opened **GParted** and there i expected to see the unallocated space that i created in windows moments ago to appear just above the root partition. **But the problem is** that there is some partition(of around 310 GB) in between the root partition and the unallocated space. Upon close inspection i found out that the 310 GB partition is actually the container that contains all my linux partitions(root,swap,home) and one of my windows partition as sublist(or child) as shown in the screenshot. Now i am unable to extend the root partition because when i right click on the root partition inside GParted then there is no space to extend to as the unallocated space(25GB) is outside that container(or list).

What should i do next?Why is this happening.How can i resolve this and use that unallocated space to extend my root partition? Is there a way to maybe move that 25.65 GB of unallocated space to inside of that 310 GB container such that the unallocated space must be above the root partition? For reference i am **attaching the screenshot** of all the steps.

[Screenshot of before creating unallocated space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMxMi.jpg)

[Screenshot of After creating unallocated space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUoRv.jpg)

[Screenshot of GParted using Live USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/671KT.jpg)

Comment: It's ubuntu 18.04.4 .I wrote that in a hurry.And i checked it's authentic at that time using the sha key they provide i think in their official site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should be simple. You need to extend sda4 into the unallocated space. That will move the unallocated space into the extended partition. Then you can resize sda6 into the unallocated space.

Your Gparted screenshot shows sda4 is locked. It shouldn’t be if you have booted into a live environment. You will have to make sure sda4 is not locked to make these changes and unmount if necessary

Comment: Yes i just did it . Ubuntu is working fine after the  whole process.

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept the answer so that others searching for accepted answers only can find it. Thanks.